# How to list buckets from YandexStorage using C# and AmazonS3Client

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yandex, yandex-api

Recently, i wrote a C# service class that successfully works with `S3` compatible services and checked that it allows me to manipulate buckets and theit contents. This code successfully works with `CloudFlare.R2` and `AWS S3`, however i was forced to migrate to Yandex Storage, and some of my functions stopped working (all operation related to buckets).

This is my interface for `S3` services, all methods that have bucket in name does not work with `Yandex.Storage` and work with i.e. `CloudFlare.R2`:

```cs
 public interface IS3CompatibleFileService
 {
     // bucket manipulation methods
     Task<IList<string>> GetBucketsAsync();
     Task<bool> CheckBucketExistsAsync(string bucketName);
     Task<bool> AddBucketAsync(string bucketName);
     Task<bool> RemoveBucketAsync(string bucketName);
     // files manipulation methods
     Task<bool> AddItemAsync(string itemName, string bucketName, string filePath);
     Task<bool> AddItemAsync(string itemName, string bucketName, byte[] content);
     Task<bool> RemoveItemAsync(string itemName, string bucketName);
     Task<bool> UpdateItemAsync(string itemName, string bucketName, string filePath);
     Task<bool> UpdateItemAsync(string itemName, string bucketName, byte[] content);
     Task<byte[]> GetItemDataAsync(string itemName, string bucketName);
}
```

Part of implementation of this interface:

```cs
public class AWSCompatibleFileStorageService : IS3CompatibleFileService, IDisposable
{
    public AWSCompatibleFileStorageService(ApplicationSettings settings, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AWSCompatibleFileStorageService>();
        try
        {
            _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(_settings.S3Storage.AccessKey, _settings.S3Storage.SecretAccessKey),
                new AmazonS3Config
            {
                ServiceURL = _settings.S3Storage.Endpoint,
                    
            });
        }
        catch(AmazonClientException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Incorrect S3 Storage configuration: {e.Message} , ensure S3Storage section has correct values");
        }
            
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_s3Client != null)
            _s3Client.Dispose();
    }

    public async Task<IList<string>> GetBucketsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            ListBucketsResponse bucketsResp = await _s3Client.ListBucketsAsync();
            return bucketsResp.Buckets.Select(b => b.BucketName).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"An error occurred during getting buckets list: {e.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> CheckBucketExistsAsync(string bucketName)
    {
        try
        {
            IList<string> buckets = await GetBucketsAsync();
            return buckets.Contains(bucketName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // other methods
}
```

I am using `https://s3.yandexcloud.net` as an operations endpoint. I've created service account with all possible Roles related to yandex storage (`storage.admin`), see:

[image]

Result of bucket list exectution is - `Access Denied`.

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.yandex.ru/ru/docs/storage/api-ref/Bucket/list) we should pass `folderId`, but i don't understand how to do this techically.
Actually, there are 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to implement all bucket operations using `AmazonS3Client`
2. if answer on 1 is 'Yes' how to configure code to do this.